# Executing notebooks manually fails

Tags: python, c++, jupyter-notebook, root-framework

I am using Jupyter notebooks with root C++ kernel in order to create some interactive documentation.

the notebooks run via my browser but when I try to use nbconvert in order to execute the notebooks via terminal the execution fails.
The command I use is this:

```
jupyter nbconvert --ExecutePreprocessor.timeout=600 --to notebook --execute ../notebooks/myfile.ipynb
```

The error is this:

```
    [NbConvertApp] Converting notebook ../notebooks/myfile.ipynb to notebook
[NbConvertApp] Executing notebook with kernel: root
[NbConvertApp] ERROR | Error while converting '../notebooks/myfile.ipynb'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/nbconvert/nbconvertapp.py", line 335, in export_single_notebook
    output, resources = self.exporter.from_filename(notebook_filename, resources=resources)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/nbconvert/exporters/exporter.py", line 165, in from_filename
    return self.from_notebook_node(nbformat.read(f, as_version=4), resources=resources, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/nbconvert/exporters/notebook.py", line 26, in from_notebook_node
    nb_copy, resources = super(NotebookExporter, self).from_notebook_node(nb, resources, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/nbconvert/exporters/exporter.py", line 130, in from_notebook_node
    nb_copy, resources = self._preprocess(nb_copy, resources)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/nbconvert/exporters/exporter.py", line 302, in _preprocess
    nbc, resc = preprocessor(nbc, resc)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/nbconvert/preprocessors/base.py", line 47, in __call__
    return self.preprocess(nb,resources)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/nbconvert/preprocessors/execute.py", line 83, in preprocess
    nb, resources = super(ExecutePreprocessor, self).preprocess(nb, resources)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/nbconvert/preprocessors/base.py", line 70, in preprocess
    nb.cells[index], resources = self.preprocess_cell(cell, resources, index)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/nbconvert/preprocessors/execute.py", line 112, in preprocess_cell
    raise CellExecutionError(msg)
nbconvert.preprocessors.execute.CellExecutionError: An error occurred while executing the following cell:
------------------
sqrt(3.)
------------------

NameError: name 'sqrt' is not defined
```

I see that the errors are from python even if my kernel is C++. Where should I be looking?

**EDIT:**

After the sugestion in the comments. I am now using this comand

```
jupyter nbconvert --ExecutePreprocessor.timeout=600 --ExecutePreprocessor.kernel_name='root' --to notebook --execute ../notebooks/myfile.ipynb
```

but the problem persists. First of all it does not seem to recognize the kernel_name attribute and secondly it still does not recognize `sqrt`

```
[NbConvertApp] WARNING | Config option `kernel_name` not recognized by `ExecutePreprocessor`.
[NbConvertApp] Converting notebook ../notebooks/2-ROOT-Basics.ipynb to notebook
[NbConvertApp] Executing notebook with kernel: root
[NbConvertApp] ERROR | Error while converting '../notebooks/2-ROOT-Basics.ipynb'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/nbconvert/nbconvertapp.py", line 335, in export_single_notebook
    output, resources = self.exporter.from_filename(notebook_filename, resources=resources)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/nbconvert/exporters/exporter.py", line 165, in from_filename
    return self.from_notebook_node(nbformat.read(f, as_version=4), resources=resources, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/nbconvert/exporters/notebook.py", line 26, in from_notebook_node
    nb_copy, resources = super(NotebookExporter, self).from_notebook_node(nb, resources, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/nbconvert/exporters/exporter.py", line 130, in from_notebook_node
    nb_copy, resources = self._preprocess(nb_copy, resources)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/nbconvert/exporters/exporter.py", line 302, in _preprocess
    nbc, resc = preprocessor(nbc, resc)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/nbconvert/preprocessors/base.py", line 47, in __call__
    return self.preprocess(nb,resources)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/nbconvert/preprocessors/execute.py", line 83, in preprocess
    nb, resources = super(ExecutePreprocessor, self).preprocess(nb, resources)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/nbconvert/preprocessors/base.py", line 70, in preprocess
    nb.cells[index], resources = self.preprocess_cell(cell, resources, index)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/nbconvert/preprocessors/execute.py", line 112, in preprocess_cell
    raise CellExecutionError(msg)
nbconvert.preprocessors.execute.CellExecutionError: An error occurred while executing the following cell:
------------------
sqrt(3.)
------------------

NameError: name 'sqrt' is not defined
```

Comment: It seems that you are running nbconvert with default kernel which is python. You need to specify `kernel_name` traitlet.

Comment: Is this possible to be used as a flag via terminal or do I have to write a script for it?

Comment: based on the nbconvert documentation it should be somthing like this
`jupyter nbconvert --ExecutePreprocessor.timeout=600 --ExecutePreprocessor.kernel_name='ROOT' --to notebook --execute ../notebooks/myfile.ipynb`
but I'm not sure if the kernel name is correct or not.
https://nbconvert.readthedocs.org/en/latest/execute_api.html#execution-arguments-traitlets

Comment: Thank a lot I changed the command but the problem is still there. The kernel_name is not recognised and the sqrt() function gives an error of "not defined.  I am editing the question with new info.

Comment: Try upgrading nbconvert, I think specifying `kernel_name` needs 4.2.0. It should pick up the correct kernel from the notebook metadata, though...